# Oracle query : Query to get Distinct Name to get maximum salary as mentioned in expected result

Tags: sql, oracle

Could you please provide me the query to get the expected result as given below.
I need to use similar logic in my nodejs application.

Table :(employee)

```
 Name    | Month     | Salary| 
-------------------------------
 Vinodh  | Jan       | 7000 | 
 Vinodh  | Feb       | 6500 | 
 Elumalai| Jan       | 8000 | 
 Elumalai| Feb       | 9000 |  
 Kumar   | Dec       | 5000 | 
 Kumar   | Feb       | 4000 |
```

Expected result :

```
 Name    | Month     | Salary| 
-------------------------------
 Vinodh  | Jan       | 7000 | 
 Elumali | Feb       | 9000 | 
 Kumar   | Dec       | 5000 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.salary = (select max(t2.salary) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

Comment: it is taking too long to execute it

Comment: @VinodhElumalai . . . Add an index on `(name, salary)`.